# Listening to Firebird events on Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebird, firebird2.5, node-firebird

I created the following event in Firebird 2.5

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER neworc FOR ORC AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  POST_EVENT 'new_orc';
END
```

I would like to know if there is a way for me to listen for this event in my node application. I installed the node-firebird package and created the code below, but it didn't work.

```js
Firebird.attach(options, function(err, db) {
    if (err)
        throw err;

    db.on('new_orc', function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of [node-firebird](https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird) does not mention Firebird events. The `on` function only seems to be for node-firebird specific connection events (*"attach, detach, row, result, transaction, commit, rollback, error, etc."*), and not for Firebird events.

In other words, it looks like you cannot listen for Firebird events using node-firebird.

The drivers of https://github.com/asfernandes/node-firebird-drivers seem to support events (e.g. see [this test](https://github.com/asfernandes/node-firebird-drivers/blob/master/packages/node-firebird-driver/src/test/tests.ts#L228)), but this library is severely underdocumented.